# Mechanize: not logged in the site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize

I'm trying to authorise to other site with gem [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize)

My code:

```
  def login_zenit
    agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.get('http://mobile.zenitbet.com/') do |p|
      f = p.forms.first
      f.login = 'login'
      f.fields[1].value = 'password'
      f.submit
    end
    agent.get('http://mobile.zenitbet.com/')
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

The problem is when I run `login_zenit` it doesn't work - I'm not authorising to the site in web browser. Although if I run this code in `rails console` it works perfectly. Where did I make a mistake? maybe there is a problem with `redirect_to root_url`?

Thanks!

Comment: What is happening versus what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I expect I authorise to the site remotely through my rails app. But it doesn't happen - I'm still not authorised on the site

Comment: As in you then point you browser at that site and expect to be logged in?

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes, I expect to be logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general is not possible. For this to work visiting your app would need to set the appropriate cookies for mobile.zenibet.com.

You do have those cookie values - they're inside the mechanize object, but even if you were to extract them you wouldn't be able to set them on the correct domain. If your app is being served from foo.com then the browser will let you set cookies on foo.com or any subdomain of it, but it won't let you set cookies on another arbitrary domain (see point 5 in section 5.3 of the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3))

Unless your app runs on a subdomain of zenibet.com I think you are out of luck